# How to set up True value in a column when value in another column contains something (is not null) by default?

Tags: sql, soql

How do I set up Boolean value in a column as True by default whenever there is updated value in another column (in my case it is a timestamp)?

Comment: use case or iif

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. (2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. (3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above. (4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;). All within the question, no images.